# Что значит строка в этом задании?

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

[image: Задание]

Есть задание. В нем непонятно пару вещей, как реализовать. Что значит вот это вот:
**- конструктор для установки начальных значений полей,
-конструктор по умолчанию,
-конструктор копирования,**
Я понимаю, как задается конструктор по умолчанию, в описании класса. Но как задать конструтор копирования и разве конструктор начальных значений-это не есть конструктор по умолчанию? И еще одно непонятно. Что значит:
**Если в конструктор передан символьный параметр,
например «а», то контролировать, начинается ли имя автора с данной буквы.** -Не понимаю как это сделать. Создать метод класса, который это реализует или что? Все пишется на С++

Answer (score 2):

Кратко:

> Я понимаю, как задается конструктор по умолчанию, в описании класса. Но как задать конструтор копирования и разве конструктор начальных значений-это не есть конструктор по умолчанию?

Итак, класс, скажем... `Class`

```
class  Class
{
    string s;
  public:
    Class();    // <-- конструктор по умолчанию (без параметров)
    Class(const string& s):s(s){};  // <-- Конструктор с параметрами (не так уж важно, какими)
                                    // он и используются для задания начальных значений полей

    Class(const Class&);  // <-- конструктор копирования - создание объекта-копии
                          // из другого объекта того же класса
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: Спасибо, в книге про конструктор копирования ничего не нашел. Так понятнее